# getAttributetext() not working when there is only one value?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product, product-attribute, magento-community

`$product->getAttributeText('att_code'); not` working when there is only one value for dropdown,multiselect attribute.

I am having a very strange problem in fetching multiselect option value on the frontend when there is only one option is selected for multiselect attribute.

Let's take an example i have a multiselect attribute "color_section" when i select two values from admin panel for any product it starts showing on frontend using  $product->getAttributeText('color_section'); but when i select single value it doesn't give anything.

Please answer if anyone have gone through this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess `getAttributeTex` is a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAttributeText()` is able to give you all the labels for a field, the "problem" is, that if only one field is chosen, it returns a `string`, if more than one field is chosen it returns an `array` of `string`s.

So you have to check whether it is an `array` or a `string` and process it.